# Add table at the end of the document in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add a table at the end of the document and i was using `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd',_TEXT_)`, however this doesn't seem to be working and the table data is not being viewed correctly.

If i just replace this command by  `document.writeln()`, the table is viewed correctly but the whole content is gone and replaced by the table.

Any idea how this should be done to keep the content and append the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `.appendChild()`. see http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Node/appendChild

or you could also use `.createElement()` to create a table and then put in the string of table rows you contruct in using `.innerHTML()`

Comment: If you can clarify this because i'm building my table using javascript so how can this be linked to .appendChild()

Comment: I know that @Neal, i meant how should this be done when i'm building a table in a loop

Comment: OK, the thing is that i'm building my table through adding HTML lines to the document so when i used the writeln, this is how i used to create the table:  document.writeln("<table border='1'>.....</table>  
My question is how to transform from this method to the one you're giving

Comment: Use createElement to create an empty table, construct your rows of the table as a string, now assign this string to the tables innerHTML

Comment: for more info on building tables dynamical http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532998(v=vs.85).aspx